# Sphinx UPDATE performance

Tags: sphinx

Sphinx 2.0.1 brings with it the ability to call UPDATE and update an individual item in an index.

Does anyone know what type of performance this brings to sphinx when called VERY frequently (as frequently as several hundred times a second)? The reason for this would be to keep a real time index of trending item scores which get updated every time a user performs an action. Obviously when there are lots of users this value can be update quite frequently.

**EDIT:**

I should mention that I am not using SphinxSE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are talking about sphinx rt indices... Updates are fast, but remember, this type of indices do not support enable_star. This means you can't perform searches like `appl*`.

Comment: Thanks, wasn't going to use a star query anyway

Comment: Note to future readers: real time (rt) indexes do support enable_star at this point in time. Just make sure you include the following in your index config:

enable_star    = 1
dict           = keywords
min_prefix_len = 1

(you'll have to adjust the formatting :))

Answer (score 0):

Such attributes are stored in memory. So updates should be really fast.

But I've never benchmarked it. So try benchmarking it!

... although to be honest I would still be tempted to 'batch process' it. Write the actions to a log "file", and then process that log in batches. Maybe every 10 seconds. All actions on the same record can be run as one update statement.